# ANE-ImagePicker displayCamera callback -

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, air, android-camera, ane

Using [ANE-ImagePicker](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-ImagePicker) (aka AirImagePicker) on 
Android 4.2+ with AIR, the displayCamera callback is never 
called.

**I am looking for the correct AS3 callback and parms declaration.**

I have the manifest set correctly and I can call the camera
via the ANE. The camera displays and a photo can be taken. The photo
even lands in the displayCamera supplied Album name ok.

However the callback (where one would actually DO something with the image)
is never called.

I have tried this:

```
protected function onImagePicked(_status:String,
_bmdData:BitmapData = null,
_baData:ByteArray = null):void
```

and this:

```
protected function onImagePicked(_status:String, _mediaArgs:Array):void
```

... neither gets called upon saving the camera photo.

What is the correct AS3 callback code?

Thank you

Comment: Well if it doesn't get called this is not your number one problem. The first problem would be to actually get the callback to run then once you have that part working you can work on getting the correct arguments. Personally I would recompile the whole thing using Events.